# Cat file, get every nth line starting at line number

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a large file.

How can I print every 9th line starting at line 6?

```
awk NR % 9 == 0' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GNU `sed` you can use the [*first~step* operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses):

```
sed -n '6~9p' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable (`lin`) which holds the line number, from line 6. If `lin` is a multiple of 9 then print the line with the line number.

```
awk '{lin=NR-6; if (!(lin %9)) print}' file1 > file2
```